# go inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: go, polymorphism

This code does not run correctly :

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Human interface {
    myStereotype() string
}

type Man struct {
}

func (m Man) myStereotype() string {
    return "I'm going fishing."
}

type Woman struct {
}

func (m Woman) myStereotype() string {
    return "I'm going shopping."
}
func main() {
    var m *Man
    m = new (Man)
    w := new (Woman)

    var hArr []*Human

    hArr = append(hArr, m)
    hArr = append(hArr, w)

    for n, _ := range (hArr) {

        fmt.Println("I'm a human, and my stereotype is: ",
                hArr[n].myStereotype())
    }
}
```

It exists with :

```
tmp/sandbox637505301/main.go:29:18: cannot use m (type *Man) as type *Human in append:
*Human is pointer to interface, not interface
tmp/sandbox637505301/main.go:30:18: cannot use w (type *Woman) as type *Human in append:
*Human is pointer to interface, not interface
tmp/sandbox637505301/main.go:36:67: hArr[n].myStereotype undefined (type *Human is pointer to interface, not interface)
```

But this one runs correctly (var hArr []*Human is rewritten into var hArr []Human) :

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Human interface {
    myStereotype() string
}

type Man struct {
}

func (m Man) myStereotype() string {
    return "I'm going fishing."
}

type Woman struct {
}

func (m Woman) myStereotype() string {
    return "I'm going shopping."
}
func main() {
    var m *Man
    m = new (Man)
    w := new (Woman)

    var hArr []Human // <== !!!!!! CHANGED HERE !!!!!!

    hArr = append(hArr, m)
    hArr = append(hArr, w)

    for n, _ := range (hArr) {

        fmt.Println("I'm a human, and my stereotype is: ",
                hArr[n].myStereotype())
    }
}
```

Output is ok:

```
I'm a human, and my stereotype is:  I'm going fishing.
I'm a human, and my stereotype is:  I'm going shopping.
```

And I do not understand why. As m and w are pointers, why when I define hArr as an array of pointers on Human the code fails ?

Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Go has no inheritance, hence there is no "is a" type polymorphism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Interfaces to Create a Queue for Arbitrary Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595810/using-interfaces-to-create-a-queue-for-arbitrary-types)

Answer (score 4):

Your primary problem is that you're using a *pointer* to an interface.  My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion/44372954#44372954) contains some details about the difference.  Suffice it to say, pointers to interfaces are almost always errors.

If you store a `*Man` into a `Human` (NOT a `*Human`), it'll work just fine because interfaces can store pointers without a problem.  In fact, in general, you want to default to storing pointers in interfaces, as values stored in interfaces cannot access pointer methods of the type stored.  An interface is simply a bucket that holds a type, and it doesn't matter whether that type is a struct or a pointer to a struct.  A *pointer* to an interface, on the other hand, is *NOT* an interface, and doesn't have the same implicit fulfillment system that interfaces have.  It's much the same as being unable to use a `*func()` variable as a function.  It's a pointer, not a function.

TL;DR: don't use pointers to interfaces.  It's almost never useful, and generally just reflects a misunderstanding of what interfaces are.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to think about interfaces as more similar to an API definition than a type. Things that satisfy the interface can already be structs or pointers, so you don't need to use an interface pointer. As stated in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372954/857156):

> Pointers to interfaces are almost never useful. In fact, the Go runtime was specifically changed a few versions back to no longer automatically dereference interface pointers (like it does for structure pointers), to discourage their use. In the overwhelming majority of cases, a pointer to an interface reflects a misunderstanding of how interfaces are supposed to work.